# Django forms - best practice to set initial values in __init__() method

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this is a broad question, but I am trying to understand the best practice way to set initial values, edit fields (make readonly for E.g) in a django form **init**() method.

Take my form for instance:

```
class ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):

    evidence = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 60}),
                label='Evidence:',
                required=False,
            )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResultForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        result_obj = self.instance
        if result_obj.tier_id:

            self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'classified' 

        else:
              ... do stuff ...

              self.initial['evidence'] = new_evidence_variable   



    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = (
                'id',
                'evidence',
                'tier_id',
            )
```

This is fine to render the unbound form, however when I attempt to validate it with POST data, the **init** method is run without a proper instance, and it fails.

My way around this, is putting my code in **init** in a try/except block:

```
class ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):

    evidence = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 60}),
                label='Evidence:',
                required=False,
            )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResultForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            result_obj = self.instance
            if result_obj.tier_id:

                self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
                self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'classified' 

            else:
                  ... do stuff ...

                  self.initial['evidence'] = new_evidence_variable   

        except:
            pass


    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = (
                'id',
                'evidence',
                'tier_id',
            )
```

This seems to work, however it seems a little hacky. Is there a 'better' or more django proposed way to do this?

Comment: A `ModelForm` always has an instance. When you create your ModelForm, you can pass it an existing instance (using `ResultForm(request.POST, instance=my_instance)`) if you're updating an existing instance, or no instance if you're creating a new instance. But `self.instance` is always initialised to a model instance so I don't understand what you mean by "the init method is run without a proper instance, and it fails". How does it fail? What's the error?

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer - I did something very daft and did not include the form.id in my template... therefore I wasn't getting the instance when the form was submitted with POST data.. duh! It works without the try method now! THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right about that. But it need following tweaks to update

If `ResultForm` class contains instance than do as following if else check

```
class ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):

    evidence = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 60}),
                label='Evidence:',
                required=False,
            )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResultForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        result_obj = self.instance
        if result.obj:   # Checks if result_obj is None or not

           self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
           self.fields['evidence'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'classified' 

        else:
           ... do stuff ...
           self.initial['evidence'] = new_evidence_variable   


    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = (
                'id',
                'evidence',
                'tier_id',
            )
```

Comment: In which case self.instance is None? I mean, when you are adding an element, you have an self.instance with all its arguments as None.